# FTC examples, questions

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the following using fundamental theorem of calculus.

A)

$$F(x)={d\over dx }\int_2^{e^x}\ \frac{\log z}{z} dz$$

B)

$$f'(x)=\log_{e^x} e^{\int_0^{x}\ e^{u^2} du}$$

I tried  for A) use the chain rule:

\begin{align}
F(x)&={d\over dx }\int_2^{e^x}\ \frac{\log z}{z} dz \\
&= \frac{\log(e^x)}{e^x} (e^x) \\
&= \frac{x}{e^x} (e^x) \\
&= x
\end{align}
Is this correct?

What should be the right way to approaching the question B)?

Comment: Are you sure the base of part $B$ is $e^{x}$?

Comment: Yes, the exercise said base e^x

Comment: Logarithm base $e^x$ (where $x$ is a variable) is **sick**.

Comment: Yes but i do not know how to solve this